# iOS System locale identifier is empty

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've noticed something weird while using date formatters. Below is the code for the date formatter.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEE dd MMM h:mm a"
formatter.locale = NSLocale.systemLocale()
print(formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) )
```

The output is: "Fri 18 M03 1:05 PM". Which is kind of weird. However removing the formatter's locale gives me the output that I want: "Fri 18 Mar 1:05 PM".

I also tried printing out NSLocale.systemLocale(), and the output is an empty string. Is that normal? And what is actually happening to the date formatter when you change the locale?

FYI: I'm testing this on an actual device. And also changing the Region formats in device settings have no affect on the locale identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the system setting, should use this one `NSLocale.currentLocale()`

In Apple's API Document already have a point on this.

**Discussion**
*Use the system locale when you don’t want any localizations. Use the current locale to format text that you display to users.*

FYI: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/systemLocale